# how to make inline editable row in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have this code for my jqgrid. I was able to achieve a `cellEdit`. But I want to achieve here is to edit the whole `row`. Because the `cellEdit` takes a lot of time, it needs to click the cell to be enable for editing.

```
function fnGridCorrected(StartDate, EndDate) {
var url1 = '../Request/_getCorrection?startDate=' + StartDate + '&endDate=' + EndDate;
$("#CorrectedList").jqGrid({
    url: url1,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['rowId', 'Id', 'Date', 'Time In1', 'Time Out1', 'Time In2', 'Time Out2', 'Time In1', 'Time Out1', 'Time In2', 'Time Out2', 'Remarks', 'Status', 'Approved By', 'Date Request', 'Date Approved'],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'rowId', index: 'rowId', hidden: true, width: 20 },
                { name: 'CorrectedId', index: 'CorrectedId', hidden: true, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 20, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 85, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'In1', index: 'In1', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 80, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'Out1', index: 'Out1', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 80, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'In2', index: 'In2', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 80, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'Out2', index: 'Out2', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 80, align: 'center' },

                { name: 'CorrectedIn1', index: 'CorrectedIn1', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 80, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'CorrectedOut1', index: 'CorrectedOut1', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 80, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'CorrectedIn2', index: 'CorrectedIn2', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 80, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'CorrectedOut2', index: 'CorrectedOut2', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 80, align: 'center' },

                { name: 'remarks', index: 'remarks', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 85, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 85, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'ApprovedBy', index: 'ApprovedBy', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 95, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'ReqDate', index: 'ReqDate', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 85, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'ApprovedDate', index: 'ApprovedDate', editable: true, hidde: false, width: 90, align: 'center' }
               ],
    pager: $('#CorrectedPager'),
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    sortname: 'Id',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    imgpath: '/Content/themes/redmond/images/',
    height: '100%',
    cellEdit: true,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    //editurl: 'clientArray',
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var objRowData = jQuery("#CorrectedList").getRowData(id);

    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        var ids = jQuery("#CorrectedList").getDataIDs();
        var len = ids.length,
            newLine;
        if (len < 5) {
            AddNewRowToGrid(len, "#CorrectedList");
        }
    }
});


$("#CorrectedList").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle: true,
    groupHeaders: [
                  { startColumnName: 'Date', numberOfColumns: 1, titleText: '' },
                  { startColumnName: 'In1', numberOfColumns: 4, titleText: 'Actual Time' },
                  { startColumnName: 'CorrectedIn1', numberOfColumns: 4, titleText: 'Correction', columnWidth: 500 }
                  ]
});
```

}

I try also this two `cellsubmit: 'clientArray'` and `rowEdit: true` but It won't enable the row. Did I do wrong in my Inline row?. BTW I am using `jqgrid 4.4.4`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to my question. In `onSelectrow` function I just add the code `jQuery('#myGrid').editRow(id, true);` to enable the whole row to be editable.